# mean.io when ran using gulp no result

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack

I installed mean.io with necessary components.

In my system(ubuntu) /home/mukund/MeanApp3 is the app directory

In terminal i entered the directory and ran gulp. Then i got the following

```
Invoking gulp - development
[17:37:22] Using gulpfile ~/MeanApp3/gulpfile.js
[17:37:22] Starting 'clean'...
[17:37:22] Finished 'clean' after 5.45 ms
[17:37:22] Starting 'default'...
[17:37:22] Starting 'coffee'...
[17:37:22] Finished 'coffee' after 9.72 ms
[17:37:22] Starting 'clean'...
[17:37:22] Starting 'less'...
[17:37:22] Starting 'csslint'...
[17:37:22] Starting 'env:development'...
[17:37:22] Finished 'env:development' after 21 μs
[17:37:22] Starting 'devServe'...
[17:37:23] Finished 'devServe' after 68 ms
[17:37:23] Starting 'watch'...
[17:37:30] Finished 'watch' after 7.86 s
[17:37:30] Finished 'clean' after 8.13 s
[17:37:31] [nodemon] v1.3.7
[17:37:31] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[17:37:31] [nodemon] watching: *.*
[17:37:31] [nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
debugger listening on port 5858
loading docs for: /home/mukund/MeanApp3/packages/core/articles
Mean app started on port 3000 (development) cluster.worker.id: 0
/home/mukund/MeanApp3/packages/custom/i18n/public/assets/lib/ng-i18next/dist/ng-i18next.js not found
/home/mukund/MeanApp3/packages/core/users/public/assets/lib/angular-jwt/dist/angular-jwt.min.js not found
/home/mukund/MeanApp3/packages/core/admin/public/assets/lib/ng-clip/src/ngClip.js not found
/home/mukund/MeanApp3/packages/custom/i18n/public/assets/lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js not found
/home/mukund/MeanApp3/packages/core/admin/public/assets/lib/zeroclipboard/dist/ZeroClipboard.js not found
/home/mukund/MeanApp3/packages/custom/i18n/public/assets/lib/i18next/i18next.js not found
[17:37:35] csslint: 3 files lint free
[17:37:35] Finished 'csslint' after 12 s
[17:37:36] Finished 'less' after 14 s
[17:37:36] Starting 'development'...
[17:37:36] Finished 'development' after 9.69 μs
```

and if i go to browser and run localhost:3000 i will get only a blank page but the page title in the tab can be seen as

`Mean-A Moedern Stack - Development`

And in the terminal these additionl details appear

```
GET / 304 - - 24.118 ms
GET /theme/assets/css/loginForms.css 304 - - 9.301 ms
GET /theme/assets/css/theme.css 304 - - 9.959 ms
GET /i18n/assets/css/i18n.css 304 - - 11.977 ms
GET /admin/assets/css/admin.css 304 - - 13.608 ms
GET /system/assets/css/common.css 304 - - 15.485 ms
GET /modules/rtl.css 304 - - 0.539 ms
GET /articles/assets/css/articles.css 304 - - 6.243 ms
GET /system/system.js 304 - - 19.669 ms
GET /admin/controllers/admin.js 304 - - 8.447 ms
GET /admin/controllers/example.js 304 - - 10.371 ms
GET /admin/controllers/modules.js 304 - - 12.814 ms
GET /admin/controllers/settings.js 304 - - 10.288 ms
GET /admin/controllers/themes.js 304 - - 12.148 ms
GET /admin/controllers/users.js 304 - - 1.169 ms
GET /admin/directives/editable.js 304 - - 3.844 ms
GET /admin/routes/admin.js 304 - - 4.394 ms
GET /admin/services/module-settings.js 304 - - 5.868 ms
GET /admin/services/modules.js 304 - - 6.765 ms
GET /admin/services/settings.js 304 - - 1.499 ms
GET /admin/services/users.js 304 - - 2.813 ms
GET /articles/controllers/articles.js 304 - - 2.021 ms
GET /articles/routes/articles.js 304 - - 2.774 ms
GET /articles/services/articles.js 304 - - 0.826 ms
GET /system/controllers/header.js 304 - - 1.777 ms
GET /system/controllers/index.js 304 - - 6.418 ms
GET /system/routes/system.js 304 - - 6.365 ms
GET /system/services/global.js 304 - - 6.513 ms
GET /system/services/interceptor.js 304 - - 5.831 ms
GET /system/services/menus.js 304 - - 7.324 ms
GET /users/services/meanUser.js 304 - - 3.340 ms
GET /users/controllers/meanUser.js 304 - - 4.214 ms
GET /users/routes/auth.js 304 - - 5.062 ms
GET /i18n/controllers/i18n.js 304 - - 3.131 ms
GET /i18n/routes/i18n.js 304 - - 4.760 ms
GET /i18n/services/i18n.js 304 - - 6.222 ms
GET /theme/controllers/theme.js 304 - - 2.101 ms
GET /theme/routes/theme.js 304 - - 3.077 ms
GET /theme/services/theme.js 304 - - 1.731 ms
GET /_getModules 304 - - 1.140 ms
GET /admin/controllers/example.js 304 - - 0.655 ms
GET /admin/controllers/modules.js 304 - - 0.730 ms
GET /favicon.ico 200 - - 3.458 ms
GET / 200 - - 1.850 ms
GET /i18n/assets/css/i18n.css 200 48 - 7.545 ms
GET /system/assets/css/common.css 200 921 - 8.409 ms
GET /modules/rtl.css 200 0 - 0.330 ms
GET /theme/assets/css/loginForms.css 200 - - 7.779 ms
GET /theme/assets/css/theme.css 200 - - 7.942 ms
GET /admin/assets/css/admin.css 200 - - 9.280 ms
GET /articles/assets/css/articles.css 200 94 - 20.396 ms
GET /system/system.js 200 512 - 17.586 ms
GET /admin/controllers/admin.js 200 - - 22.030 ms
GET /admin/controllers/example.js 200 545 - 5.629 ms
GET /admin/controllers/modules.js 200 413 - 5.782 ms
GET /admin/controllers/settings.js 200 - - 0.652 ms
GET /admin/controllers/themes.js 200 - - 1.263 ms
GET /admin/services/module-settings.js 200 992 - 1.984 ms
GET /admin/controllers/users.js 200 - - 4.516 ms
GET /admin/routes/admin.js 200 - - 2.388 ms
GET /admin/directives/editable.js 200 - - 4.283 ms
GET /admin/services/modules.js 200 341 - 0.568 ms
GET /admin/services/settings.js 200 1007 - 0.661 ms
GET /admin/services/users.js 200 314 - 1.660 ms
GET /articles/services/articles.js 200 301 - 1.223 ms
GET /articles/controllers/articles.js 200 - - 1.952 ms
GET /articles/routes/articles.js 200 - - 1.754 ms
GET /system/controllers/header.js 200 - - 0.888 ms
GET /system/controllers/index.js 200 - - 0.878 ms
GET /system/routes/system.js 200 - - 0.677 ms
GET /system/services/global.js 200 455 - 1.105 ms
GET /system/services/interceptor.js 200 826 - 1.335 ms
GET /system/services/menus.js 200 218 - 2.144 ms
GET /users/controllers/meanUser.js 200 - - 1.132 ms
GET /users/routes/auth.js 200 - - 0.694 ms
GET /users/services/meanUser.js 200 - - 1.607 ms
GET /i18n/controllers/i18n.js 200 240 - 0.464 ms
GET /i18n/routes/i18n.js 200 233 - 1.042 ms
GET /i18n/services/i18n.js 200 123 - 2.228 ms
GET /theme/controllers/theme.js 200 254 - 0.546 ms
GET /theme/routes/theme.js 200 249 - 0.645 ms
GET /theme/services/theme.js 200 126 - 0.492 ms
GET /_getModules 200 339 - 0.409 ms
GET /favicon.ico 200 - - 1.030 ms
GET /favicon.ico 304 - - 0.806 ms
```

I dont know anything about mean.io, i was hoping to learn it. Is this really how the app should be ran?

I just want a page saying hellow world.. How to check if i have installed and configured mean.io correctly?

I have installed node.js, mongodb, swagger-express, bower gulp, i18next

Someone please help

Comment: did you ran npm install ? and also check the browser console for errors.

Comment: yes i did ran npm install

Comment: what about the browser console?

Comment: just nothing shows in browser uncaught reference error angular not defined in application.js,config.js, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the port and db name in config file .

In config/env/development.js for development and config/env/production.js for production.

Comment: Here is what i did, I figured out all the files were in my app folder, but they were not in the corresponding path, so I just copy pasted it in the paths where the error log says its missing and its working now

Answer (score 1):

I got something similar error . What went wrong is bower is not installing the dependancies. The reason is the firewall blocking my git so first i set it to download from https

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Then run

```
npm cache clean
bower cache clean
```

After that run npm install once again. I did the trick for me.

Comment: so first i have to run your command `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://` then this`git clone https://github.com/meanjs/mean.git meanjs` and then this `wget https://github.com/meanjs/mean/archive/master.zip -O meanjs.zip; unzip meanjs.zip; rm meanjs.zip` and then clean npn cache, bower cache, enter the directory the run `sudo npm && bower install`?

Comment: yes that's whats i have done. It will set all git calls through https .

Comment: that's weird . you should get some kind of error somewhere.

Comment: Look at here, i added the code `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>` in my `layout.server.view.html` file(i dont know if i could add it or not) but the all the angular errors disappeared and now this error `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]`

Comment: actually you really don't need to add angular js. It's already imported if you  installed it using bower. check the network in browser after removing this script tag

Comment: @Mukund did you fix it?

Comment: Yes, after i installed angularjs inside my meanjs folder the problem was solved

Comment: so you installed angular using bower?

Comment: yup, but dere is a si ilar problem with mean.io, now mean.js is working fine and giving the site at localhost:3000

Comment: that's because both use same mongo db name and same port . Use different db name and port.

Comment: so where should i change the port and db name? which file?

Comment: in meanjs or meanio ?